# perl foreach eat all array content

Tags: perl

The follow code will eat content in @populations

```
@populations=("EUR","AFR","ASN","AMR");
print @populations,"\n";  #will show EURAFRASNAMR
foreach (@populations)
{  
    $filepath="tmp.txt"; #whatever text file you like 
    open(FILE,"<$filepath");
    while(<FILE>)
    {   
    }   
}   
print @populations,"\n";   #will print nothing
```

if change to

```
foreach $i (@populations)
```

then the array will not be eaten.

or if mark the while loop, the array will not be eaten.

I am not a perl guru, but have several years experience.

can anyone tell me why? is it a bug of perl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (<$fh>) { ... }
```

gets replaced with

```
while (defined($_ = <$fh>)) { ... }
```

which is why the value read is available in `$_`. The catch is that `$_` is currently aliased to an element of `@populations`.

As you said, you can avoid that problem by using

```
for my $population (@populations) {  
   ...
   while (<FILE>) { ... $_ ... }
   ...
}
```

But that can still clobber `$_` from the calling sub. Here are two more robust fixes:

```
for (@populations) {  # Or: for my $population (@populations) {  
   ...
   while (my $line = <FILE>) { ... $line ... }
   ...
}
```

or

```
for (@populations) {  # Or: for my $population (@populations) {  
   ...
   while (local $_ = <FILE>) { ... $_ ... }
   ...
}
```

For exactly the same reason, you shouldn't use global variables for file handles.

```
$filepath="tmp.txt"; #whatever text file you like 
open(FILE,"<$filepath");
<FILE>
```

should be

```
my $filepath="tmp.txt";
open(my $FILE, "<", $filepath) or die $!;
<$fh>
```

By the way, always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 6):

Not a bug exactly, but it is a trap for the unwary. You are implicitly assigning the elements of `@populations` to the `$_` variable, and then you are reading data from the `FILE` filehandle into `$_`, overwriting the contents of `@populations`.

More explicitly, your code is equivalent to:

```
@populations=("EUR","AFR","ASN","AMR");
print @populations,"\n";  #will show EURAFRASNAMR
foreach $_ (@populations)    # $_ becomes "aliased" to the element in @populations
{  
    $filepath="tmp.txt"; #whatever text file you like 
    open(FILE,"<$filepath");
    while(defined($_ = <FILE>))  # overwrites $_, and erases element in @populations
    {   
    }   
}   
print @populations,"\n";   #will print nothing
```

You found a good workaround, which is to avoid using `$_` implicitly in a `for` loop.